# ToolStripMenuItem bigger vertical padding, or vertically centering text in a bigger ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, padding, toolstripmenu

I'm trying to set a bigger vertical padding for *ToolStripMenuItems* in a *ContextMenuStrip*. However, changing the *Padding.Top* property adds padding to the bottom, instead of the top.

I also tried setting a larger *Height* for the *ToolStripMenuItem*, it works, however, the text always gets aligned on top, even if the *TextAlign* property is *MiddleCenter*. It should be vertical aligned to the center!

I've tried different settings for different properties, nothing works. The idea is that I cannot get the *ToolStripMenuItem* to have more space around its text, both to the top and to the bottom.

I'm using C#, Windows Forms, Net 2.0, Visual Studio 2010 Express, Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the same effect using `Margin` instead of `Padding` which will keep the `Text` of the `ToolStripMenuItem` aligned.

The drawback is that this wont modify the size of the highlight rectangle when the item is selected so it can look a little strange if you increase a lot the height.

Comment: You can adjust the "TextRectangle" of the ToolStripMenuItem's renderer if you add a few lines of code. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to InBetween's answer, you can fix the highlight rectangle by using a custom renderer and adjusting its "TextRectangle" property. Here's some sample code:

```
    var itemHeight = 36;
    var verticalPadding = 36 - TextRenderer.MeasureText("A", _DisplayNameFont).Height) / 2;
    menu.Renderer = new MyRenderer { VerticalPadding = verticalPadding };

    class MyRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer
    {
        public int VerticalPadding { get; set; }

        protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null == e)
            { return; }
            e.TextFormat &= ~TextFormatFlags.HidePrefix;
            e.TextFormat |= TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
            var rect = e.TextRectangle;
            rect.Offset(0, VerticalPadding);
            e.TextRectangle = rect;
            base.OnRenderItemText(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a new line does the job.

It's not the best solution, but it's a quick way to add some padding.

Works well when adding support for small touch screens.

```
this.configToolStripMenuItem.Text = "\r\nSettings";
```